# Returning values from a second array

Tags: java, arrays

Currently my code returns the highest temperature value that was submitted when the user enters in temperature values for each month. How can I get the program to return the month with the highest entry, instead of the highest entry itself?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reader {

static String months[] =
    {
            "January" , "February" , "March" , "April" , "May" ,
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
            "December"
    };

public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] avgMonth;
    int tempRecords = 0;
    double tempSum = 0;
    double avgTemp;
    double getHotMonth;

    //collect user input for avg temp and put into an array with the month
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    avgMonth = new int[months.length];
    for(int i=0; i < months.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the average temperature for the month of "+months[i]);
        avgMonth[i] = input.nextInt();  
    }


    //call avgTemp, takes array of temps as argument, return total avg for year
    for(int i=0;i<months.length; i++)
        tempSum += avgMonth[i];

    avgTemp = tempSum/months.length;

    //call getHotMonth, takes entire array as argument, find index of hottest month
    getHotMonth = avgMonth[0];
    for (int i=0;i<months.length;i++){
        if (avgMonth[i] > getHotMonth) 
            getHotMonth = avgMonth[i];
    }       

    //displayResults, display average and hottest month
    //args are average and the index array number of hottest month
    //final output

    displayResults(avgTemp,getHotMonth);

    input.close();

}//close main

public static void displayResults(double average, double getHotMonth){
    System.out.println("The average temperature for the year was "+average+" degrees F with "+getHotMonth+" being the hottest month.");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the `hotMonth` as well during the iteration and send it as an argument to `displayResults` method as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    //add your existing code

    String hotMonth="";
    for (int i=0;i<months.length;i++){
        if (avgMonth[i] > getHotMonth) {
            getHotMonth = avgMonth[i];
            hotMonth = months[i];//capture hotMonth
        }
     }       
     displayResults(avgTemp,hotMonth);
  }

   public static void displayResults(double average, String hotMonth){
    System.out.println("The average temperature for the year 
        was "+average+" degrees F with "+
         hotMonth+" being the hottest month.");
   }
```

Comment: The printed out result left the hotMonth result blank, nothing came from it in the final statement. Do you know what the problem would be?